# Shopify Liquid Empty Collection

Tags: shopify, liquid

`featured-collection-custom.liquid`

```
<section class="container">
  <h2>Featured Collection</h2>
  <div>{{ collections[section.settings.featured_collection].products }}</div>
  <div style="font-size: 2rem">Count: {{ collections[section.settings.featured_collection].products | size }}</div>
  
  {% for product in section.settings.featured_collection.products %}
    <div>{{ product.title }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</section>

{% schema %}

{
  "name": "Featured Collection",
  "class": "featured-collection-schema",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "collection",
      "id": "featured_collection",
      "label": "Collection"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Title",
      "default": "Featured Collection"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "category": "Collection",
      "name":"Featured Collection Custom"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

`Output:`
[image]

`Collection`
[image]

I am new to the Liquid. I have created a Collection (Test Collection)  with 5 products inside it and select 'Test Collection' as the value of collection, and why the size of the collection is 0, instead of 5?

Comment: use `products_count` instead if size, [check here](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/collection#collection-products_count)

Comment: `products_count` is 0 too.

Comment: Why using in this way `collections[section.settings.featured_collection].products` use directly like this one `{{section.settings.featured_collection.products_count}}`

Comment: I follow a course and use the same syntax, I have asked in the Q&A section yesterday and still waiting for the reply. I have tried to change it to `{{ section.settings.featured_collection.products_count }}` and still got 0 length of collection.

Comment: Nvm, After several hours searching and changing many things. I found out that the products that I populate using `shopify populate` didn't set the `Sales Channel and Apps` to my sales channel. When I add the products, it works perfectly. Thanks for the help @Onkar.